# What is the difference between the Greek words "pragma" and "pragmaton"

Tags: greek, word-study, grammar, hebrews, faith

In Hebrews 11:1 the word πραγμάτων (pragmaton) is used:

> Ἔστιν δὲ πίστις ἐλπιζομένων ὑπόστασις, **πραγμάτων** ἔλεγχος οὐ βλεπομένων.

> "Now faith is the assurance of things hoped for, the conviction of **things** not seen."

What is the difference between the Greek words "pragma" and "pragmaton", and what is the relation between these two terms.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  For this question, do you have a specific Bible passage in mind?

Comment: Thank you very much, yes the passage of scripture is Hebrews 11:1

Comment: Genitive plural https://biblehub.com/greek/4229.htm

Comment: Welcome Cisumino, thanks for your contribution! I've edited your question to include your passage, which will keep your question on-topic and help avoid it being closed unnecessarily. Please do take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the Stack Exchange format and the scope of this site.

Comment: πραγμάτων is the genitive neuter plural of πρᾶγμα, the nominative neuter singular, [Strong 4229](https://biblehub.com/greek/4229.htm). See [Biblehub Interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/hebrews/11-1.htm).

Comment: If you had a question about the meaning of the text, _the way in which the words are used_, I think you would need to ask another question. As it stands, this is a grammatical enquiry, easily answered in comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is different cases of the same noun.  The noun is neuter.
πρᾶγμα is the nominative singular.  πρᾶγματος is the genitive singular.  This word only occurs as πραγμάτων (genitive plural) four times in the New Testament.  This is beginning Greek grammar and hopefully doesn't need a reference.